# Passing an instance of user-defined class as data to a ServiceStack PUT

Tags: c#, javascript, rest, servicestack

I'm relatively new to ServiceStack and RESTful services in general and I'm running into the following roadblock:

I have a ServiceStack request object similar to the following (in C#):

```
[Authenticate]
[Route("/product", "POST")]
[Route("/product/{productId}", "GET,PUT,DELETE")]
public class SomeProductRequest: IReturn<Dto.Product>
{
    public int ProductId{ get; set; } 
    public ProductStuff SomeProductProperties { get; set; }
}
```

I can build the object in Javascript on the client-side preparing for a PUT like so:

```
var product = {
  productId: 100,
  someProductProperties: { id:5, name:"My Name" }
};
```

However, whenever the request reaches the server, the `SomeProductProperties` will always be `null`.  In fact, I'm unable to pass user-defined types to the server at all.  Only basic, baked-in .NET types seem to go over the wire (int, string, etc.)

Is there some trick to having a property of a user-defined class in the request object?

All help is very much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It's not enough context to show just the JavaScript object literal, you should also show how you're calling it and ideally the full HTTP Request + Response that you can get from WebInspector or Fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out after discussing with a colleague.  For the benefit of everybody else, here is what I did:

When sending a complex type across the wire, you need to wrap your js object that contains the complex type using `JSON.stringify()` and pass the resulting string instead:

```
var updatedUser = self.buildUserObjectFromGui();
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(updatedUser),
    url: 'internal/user/' + this.options.userId
});
```